# Googleapiclient python fit api

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-fit, google-client

Is there googleapiclient example or documentation for google fit 
i can't find any documentation about google fit api for python
all example i found is for google drive 
like

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
drive = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
  API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

files = drive.files().list().execute()
```

Comment: Well what you have there isnt going to work very well as you appear to be mixing in google drive.

Comment: i need documentation for fit api  like  this google drive code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have there isn't going to work very well as it appears to be related to Google drive.

```
def retrieve_data():
    """
    Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials.
    Returns a dataset (Users.dataSources.datasets):
    https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/datasets
    """
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    print 'Go to the following link in your browser:'
    print authorize_url
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

    # Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    fitness_service = build('fitness', 'v1', http=http)

    return fitness_service.users().dataSources(). \
              datasets(). \
              get(userId='me', dataSourceId=DATA_SOURCE, datasetId=DATA_SET). \
              execute()
```

Check this file for the full code [Getfit.py](https://gist.github.com/cedricbonhomme/a8c96f1aeb41393dadf6)  and make sure you set up your redirect URIs properly

Comment: worked but i have one question why time in nanosecond not millisecond in data_set param